# Why is it safe to use before_action :authenticate_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to both web and Rails, and I found that it is a common usage to put something like this in the beginning of a controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_admin, only: [:only_admin]
```

where

```
def authenticate_admin
  unless current_user.admin?
    flash[:alert] = "You are not admin!"
    redirect_to '/'
  end
end
```

Considering if it's possible to somehow ignore this redirection from the client side, I feel really unsafe. How is `redirect_to` implemented? Why can this usage assure safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect_to` will - well terminate your current HTTP request and require the client to initiate a new call to `/`, which is supposed to be a public page. You could redirect wherever you want.

In other words, it's a HTTP redirect.

The code first checks if the user is an admin. If not, it "alerts" the message and redirects the client to `/`.

If you are asking if you can ignore this redirect on the server by removing this call, you shouldn't ignore the redirect, otherwise you just check if the user is admin but are not taking any action. Effectively, the code is obligating the client to go to `/`. Assuming that that URL is safe to use for non-admins, this is safe.

If you are asking if the client (the browser) is able to ignore the redirect - it's not possible for the client to ignore this redirect; rails will terminate the connection and issue a HTTP redirect, which the browser can't ignore, because it's on HTTP level.

Consider reframing your question to be more precise